# Layers missing when exporting to PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, layers, export

I have created a business card in InDesign and when I export the card as a PDF or JPG it is missing the background colour and a vector image I created. I have all layers selected when exporting.

Comment: A number of things can be wrong there. Post a screenshot of your InDesign with the file open?

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess: Explore also layer options. All layers that have something to be printed should have "Print Layer" selected in its Layer Options. Unchecked "Print Layer" keeps that layer also out of exports.

[image]